# Implementation of Vanet B-MFR routing protocol on ns2

Tags: routes, ns2

is there anyway to implement VANET's B-MFR routing protocol with ns2? I searched through internet for some days, but found nothing. I found paper/journal that discuss the protocol with ns2 implmentation, this is the [link](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume48/number10/pxc3880153.pdf) . But, still I get nothing of how to implement it with ns2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot find any implementation for ns2, you could try to implement it from scratch.

For example [this document](http://imtl.skku.ac.kr/~hjlim99/ns2/%5b%BB%F5%B7%CE%BF%EE%20%B6%F3%BF%EC%C6%C3%20%C7%C1%B7%CE%C5%E4%C4%DD%20%B1%B8%C7%F6%5d/Implementing%20a%20New%20Manet%20Unicast%20Routing%20Protocol%20in%20ns2.pdf) has detailed instructions on how you would proceed.

In summary, you have to define the packet types for the protocol, then the routing agent (including hooks, timers and the agents) and the routing table.

Otherwise, you could just ask the authors of the paper to share their code with you. It is possible that they will do it.